# Setting Up CDN...beginner questions

Tags: web-hosting, google-analytics, cdn, mediatemple

I am using MediaTemple web hosting and they are using Edgecast's CDN network. I am planning to join CDN service, so I read through [the guide](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1849/Getting+started+with+ProCDN#procdn), but I am confused about the 'Update your code' section:

Does the CDN apply to my website automatically (without editing HTML) after I updated the DNS zone file? How can I control which files going through the CDN or not?

Also, I need to make sure it won't affect the Google Analytics results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it applies to your website automatically. However if you want more control, then you need to "research more advanced configurations" (as they say) yourself, or ask in the forums.

One drawback with not doing anything else is

> The default caching time for static content is 7 days. This means that
>   when you upload a new version of a file on your origin server, it
>   won't be immediately visible over the ProCDN. ...

I wouldn't have thought it would affect Analytics, as Google's code is being loaded from their servers anyway, and if it's in the HTML files it doesn't matter which server it's actually coming from. I'd monitor it though to see if the number of visits change, for example.

Comment: Are you using ProCDN? Does it mean the CDN would automatically delivery static contents like images from CDN and non-static contents like HTML from original server? Thanks!!

Comment: Somebody using MaxCDN told me he need to edit the HTML files to control what files would download from CDN..

Comment: I'm not using it, I've just been reading the manual. HTML is static. It would read dynamic content, like PHP pages from the original server. Controlling just what files download from the CDN sounds like advanced configuration.

Comment: I see, did you setup other CDNs before? I wonder CDN would normally work without editing the code..

Comment: It's all that DNS stuff that acts as a proxy so the user hits their server first which decides whether to give them the stuff that it's cached from your original site.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to contact MT's support to confirm rather than waiting for responses from their forum, it seems nobody visiting there.